Dagger-2 cannot provide a dependency from another module
I've run into the fact that I can't inject a repository into my view model. I have two modules app and data. In I build all dependencies through Application Component
@Component(
    dependencies = [DataComponent::class],
    modules = [AppModule::class, NavigationModule::class],
)
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun injectApp(app: App)
    fun inject(fragment: FirstFragment)
    fun inject(fragment: SecondFragment)
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}

@Module
abstract class DataBinds {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindAuthRepository(authRepositoryImpl: AuthRepositoryImpl): AuthRepository
}


@Component(modules = [DataBinds::class])
interface DataComponent

On the app, I'm already putting everything together
class App : Application() {
    lateinit var appComponent: ApplicationComponent
    lateinit var dataComponent: DataComponent
    val cicerone: Cicerone<Router> by lazy {
        Cicerone.create()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        dataComponent = DaggerDataComponent.builder().build()
        appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .dataComponent(dataComponent)
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .build()
    }

}

And inject the dependency in the view model
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(private val authRepository: AuthRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow("test")
    val stateFlow = _stateFlow

    fun checkUserLoggedIn() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            authRepository.isUserAuthorized().collect {
            _stateFlow.value = "User is logged in: $it"
           }
        }
    }
}

But I get an error when checking the graph
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ru.yangel.domain.repository.AuthRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
^
I tried just adding modules to the App Component and everything worked, but I want to do as a multi-module architecture where in each module I will store a different small graph and assemble it into one big one in the app

You need to add the provider method to ApplicationComponent
@Component(
    dependencies = [DataComponent::class],
    modules = [AppModule::class, NavigationModule::class],
)
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun injectApp(app: App)
    fun inject(fragment: FirstFragment)
    fun inject(fragment: SecondFragment)
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

    fun provideAuthRepository(): AuthRepository // << this
}

Maybe to DataComponent too
